# Can one map more than one string to NULL in an SQL COPY command?

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, null

My current working code for a single nullable value:

```
COPY table FROM 'file.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER NULL AS 'NA';
```

My attempted solutions:

```
COPY table FROM 'file.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER NULL AS  'NA',' ','' ;
COPY table FROM 'file.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER NULL AS ('NA',' ','');
COPY table FROM 'file.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER NULL IN ('NA',' ','');
```

Expected result: `file.csv` imports with all values matching the strings `'NA'`, `' '` and `''` converted to `NULL`

Current result: syntax errors

Comment: Does your current code replaces na with null?

Comment: Perfect, though slightly disappointing... thanks!